# Error "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements" when trying to add data to indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I have no idea what's wrong with this code:

```
onupgradeneeded = function(){
  z = e.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
                       'record', 
                       {keyPath:'id',autoIncrement:true}
  );
  z.createIndex('book', 'book', {unique:false});
  z.createIndex('user', 'user', {unique:false});
}
```

When I try to put data into the object store using the following code:

```
db.transaction('record',IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE)
    .objectStore('record')
    .add({book:...,user:...})
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createIndex` needs to be called from within a `setVersion` transaction (spec previous to Dec. 2011, supported by current versions of Chrome and IE) and from a `onupgradeneeded` callback in the latest spec (currently supported only by FF, but IE10 and later versions of Chrome will upgrade to this).

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-createIndex-IDBIndex-DOMString-name-DOMString-keyPath-IDBIndexParameters-optionalParameters) description of `createIndex` lays out why you're seeing the error you're seeing:

> createIndex: This method creates and returns a new index with the given
>   name and parameters in the connected database. If this function is
>   called from outside a VERSION_CHANGE transaction callback, the
>   implementation must throw an DOMException of type InvalidStateError
>   exception.

For more info on the difference between `setVersion` and `onupgradeneeded`, check out [this post from IE folks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/03/21/indexeddb-updates-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx), which explains the changes in code.